# Using abbreviations for parameter-value input pairs - why does cellfun's `'UniformOutput', false` work as `'un', 0`?

Tags: matlab

As a frequent user of `cellfun(..., 'UniformOutput', false)`, I was surprised to discover that the latter two arguments could be input as `cellfun(..., 'un', 0)`. This has immediately shortened my code. My question is, are there any another similar shortcuts/aliases out there?

This doesn't appear to be documented on the MathWorks website. Naughty!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Background

The property part of a Property-value pair can be often be shortened to the beginning of the property string so long as it is still uniquely identifiable (*see examples below*). They are also often not case sensitive.
As far as I know this is not documented for anything other than figure properties, where it [is very briefly documented.](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/core-graphics-objects.html#f7-45365)

However this behaviour is also implemented in many The MathWorks functions which take property-value pair arguments, and also in some functions which take string arguments with no value pair.

The problems become what other properties are there...

- For some functions is not well documented... (and many are either
  built-in or obfuscated .p files, so no checking the source).
- Most importantly we *cannot know if future versions will introduce new
  properties*.

The use of shortened property names is **advised against** for this reason, to quote

> "using the full property name can prevent problems with futures releases of MATLAB if a shortened name is no longer unique because of the addition of new properties." - [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/core-graphics-objects.html#f7-45365)
>
> "*Don't shorten your code with P-V abbreviations, it's not worth it, trust me*." –  [Sam Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169781/sam-roberts)

The brief slightly technical side - This functionality is implemented by default by Matlabs `inputParser`, however it *can be disabled* so these abbreviations are by no means guaranteed to work on every function. Only those which use the `inputParser` in this way or are specifically written to allow this.

---

### Examples using figure properties

1. **Simple Shortening**

The following

```
hFig = figure();
get(Hfig,'Visible')
ans =

on
```

can be shortened to

```
hFig = figure();
get(Hfig,'v')
ans =

on
```

as it is the only property beginning with `'v'` (note that `'vi'`,`'vis'`, etc... also work)

2. **Uniqueness**

However other properties which start similarly e.g. `CurrentAxes`, `CurrentCharacter` & `CurrentObject`

```
get(Hfig,'Current')

Error using get
Ambiguous property found.
Object Name: figure
Property Name: 'Current'.
```

Where as `'currenta'`,`'currentc'` and `'currento'` are uniquely identifiable and would work as intended

3. **Impossible to shorten**

A special mention to properties such as `Color` and `ColorMap` the name of one is the beginning of another
`Color` can only be used with its full name, due to any shortening being ambiguous with `ColorMap`
`'ColorMap'` can be shorted to `'colorm'` however, as before.

---

### Counter examples

This section aims to **discourage** use of shortened property value pairs by showing some of the seemingly *unpredictable* and *unexpected* behaviour.

The semi-undocumented `hardcopy` has some interesting behaviour the documentation states possible options as -dps,-deps,-dps2,-deps2,-dill,-dhpgl

However `'-dh'` creates an error where as `'-di'`  works as an abbreviated `'-dill'` sadly there is  no checking the source to see why as it is a .p file

Finally `cellfun` itself doesn't exactly follow there rules as `'u'` should theoretically work if following the rules above, however only `'un'` and onwards does.

Comment: So there is some method to this; thanks very much for your explanation.

Comment: I should add that `cellfun` also breaks this slightly as `'u'` although appearing uniquely identifiable does not work...

Comment: + 1 I had exactly the same suspicion. Now I see a confirmation, or, at least, a similar opinion

Comment: Shortening every property string in a script to the minimum required would be a fun prank to play on someone trying to debug the function :)

Comment: It's not quite true that every parameter-value pair can be abbreviated. When writing your own functions, you would need to specifically implement that behavior. If you use `inputParser` to parse your inputs, it will do that by default, but even then you can choose to turn it off, and it will turn off automatically if you use `structExpand`. In general, MathWorks implement _their_ functionality so that abbreviations work that way, but even they aren't always consistent in doing that. There are plenty of MATLAB and toolbox functions that do not support parameter-value abbreviations.

Comment: PS Parameter-value abbreviations are a *horrible* design choice, and I really encourage everyone to *never* use or support them in their code. Imagine you've written some code that uses `cellfun(..., 'un', false)`. In the next version of MATLAB, MathWorks introduce a new option to `cellfun`, maybe calling it `'Unit'` - which would be a perfectly fine thing for them to do, since it's not an existing option. Suddenly all your code breaks, as the abbreviation you used is no longer unambiguous. *Don't shorten your code with P-V abbreviations, it's not worth it, trust me.*

Comment: @SamRoberts +1 I agree totally... and in the brief documentation which exist they do warn of this... I do however use them regularly in throwaway code e.g. in the command window

Comment: @SamRoberts, RTL I would include Sams comments in the answer, or Sam should write a new one. Seems pretty important to me.

Answer (score 4):

If a routine uses MATLAB's `inputParser` functionality then usually any parameter name can be shortened such that it is still unambiguous and is matched case insensitively.  The same is true for properties of objects such as `get(gcf, 'pos')` as a shorter version of `get(gcf, 'Position')`.

However, I don't know if there is any documentation on this usage and I suggest you try it and see.

And `0` is usually equivalent to `false` (non-zero being `true`).

PS I would suggest that using these shortcuts is fine at the command line but when writing functions and scripts it is better to use the full names.

Comment: Got it, thanks very much for your explanation. I'll go have a look at the inputParser to learn more about it.