# Define ranges for multiple values

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays

```
A=[1;2]

B= [5;6]
```

Now I want to have the matrix C = A:B such that

```
C = [1 2 3 4 5; 2 3 4 5 6]
```

How can I do this in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html?refresh=true) in combination with [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) like this:

```
A =
     1     4     7    10   
B =
     5     8    11    14

cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n) (A(n):B(n)), 1:numel(A),'UniformOutput', false)')
ans =

     1     2     3     4     5
     4     5     6     7     8
     7     8     9    10    11
    10    11    12    13    14
```

You can shorten it down a bit using an abbreviation for `UniformOutput`, but I suggest writing it out since the abbreviations might no longer be unambiguous in future MATLAB versions. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907412/using-abbreviations-for-parameter-value-input-pairs-why-does-cellfuns-unifo) for a lengthy discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your question implicitly assumes that `B(1)-A(1)` equals `B(2)-A(2)` etc; otherwise the result is undefined.

You can do it quite generally and efficiently as follows: build the first row, and then use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to obtain all other rows:

```
C = bsxfun(@plus, A(1):B(1), A(:)-A(1));
```

Comment: Obviously the best solution. I haven't benchmarked (no need really), but I would think this is _at least_ an order of magnitude faster than the arrayfun-approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
C = [A(1,1):B(1,1);A(2,1):B(2,1)];
```

Comment: I have to do this for thousands. So this is not the efficient way

Comment: Well why don't you expand on your question a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
C=[ A(1):1:B(1); A(2):1:B(2) ]
```