# Programmatically determine if a script is being published or executed normally

Tags: matlab, publish

Prior to release R2016a, [publishing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html) is *the* way in MATLAB to document the results of a script.  I find that when I run a script manually, I often place `pause` commands throughout my script.  Is there a simple way to determine if a script is getting published or not?  Then, I can wrap my pauses in a bit of code like:

```
if isNotPublishing
    pause();
end
```

My google foo has failed me in finding a solution to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to see if `publish` is in the call stack. `dbstack` will return an array of `struct`s indicating which functions were called in what order to get to the point at which we call `dbstack`. We can use the `name` property to tell us the names of all of these functions and look to see if `publish` is among them. If it is, then we assume that the script was called via `publish`.

```
stack = dbstack;
isBeingPublished = ismember('publish', {stack.name});
```

Or if you want that to be a one-liner

```
isBeingPublished = ismember('publish', cellfun(@(x)x.name, dbstack, 'UniformOutput', 0));
```

This should work whether you publish your script using the **Publish** toolbar or from the command line with

```
publish('myscript.m')
```

If you wanted to get really fancy, you could overload `pause` (or write your own version, `mypause`) that does this check for you. This works because within your new `pause` function, `dbstack` will still contain `publish` because you called it from your script which was ultimately evaluated by `publish`. If you create this function, then you wouldn't need all of that logic within your code and could just call `mypause()` instead.

```
function mypause(varargin)
    stack = dbstack;
    if ~ismember('publish', {stack.name});
        builtin('pause', varargin{:})
    end
end
```

Comment: Nice answer! A comment/warning to anyone that's not too familiar with MATLAB. MATLAB lets you [shorten the names of parameter pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25907412/2338750) if they could be uniquely identified in fewer letters. So, `uni, 0` is short for `UniformOutput, false`. The pitfall is: If Mathworks decides that they want a `UniformInput`, `UniqueOutput`, `Ùniversal` or something like that, all codes with `uni` will fail. I would therefore suggest that you always take the time to write the full name for parameter pairs.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Great point. I always use `'uni'` out of habit but will definitely make an effort to spell it out. Thanks.

Comment: In my matlab library start up function, I have:  cu = @(f,x)cellfun(f,x,'UniformOutput',false);  Cleans up code like you wouldn't believe.

Comment: What I did not appreciate the first time I read this answer, is the clever call to builtin to handle varargin for the mypause wrapper.  Very slick.  This solves a few other problems I have.  You have now answered two questions that I've had!